# Update GA's Event Category when Event Action = "something"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to update the GA table in BigQuery.

I want to update all event categories where event action = "click"

It has been a challenge for me as this information is nested in the hits column and I cannot get any UPDATE SQL to work.

I have tried the following SQL.

```
UPDATE `my_sample_table`
SET hits =
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT eventInfo.* REPLACE('UX' AS eventCategory)) AS eventInfo)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventAction = 'click'
  )
WHERE TRUE;
```

And it does work and replace all eventCategory with 'UX' where eventAction = 'click'. But the resulting table is all unnested. I need it to be the same as the original table with hits and other fields nested.

This is as close as I got.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: While someone else will probably provide you with a technical solution, I am proposing a different sort of solution.  Use your table as a 'source' or 'staging' table and create a view (or write to a new table) that does transformations such as this.  Updating this GA table will not apply the updates when viewing through the GA app.  If someone tries to run a report on GA for this event, they will be unable to replicate with your modified data.  Just something to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
UPDATE `my_sample_table`
SET hits =
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT eventInfo.* REPLACE(
        IF(eventInfo.eventAction='click','UX', eventInfo.eventCategory) AS eventCategory
      )
    ) AS eventInfo)
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  )
WHERE TRUE
```

The problem with your initial query was in fact that you applied filtering in wrong place. Instead you need to apply it in the most inner REPLACE()

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I used your SQL but changed the inner WHERE to TRUE and it works.

Comment: Oh. of course. that one needs to be removed as it is not needed and exactly was the problem. I wll update the answer